# codeigniter pagination display same value on all page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new in codeigniter and I work on its pagination function. but I face one issue that it display same value on all page. here is my code

**Controller**

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/dashboard/productcolor/'.$id;
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->mdashboard->getAllcolorIDCount($id);
        $config["full_tag_open"] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        $config["full_tag_close"] = "</ul>";
        $config["num_tag_open"] = "<li>";
        $config["num_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["cur_tag_open"] = "<li class='active'>";
        $config["cur_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["prev_tag_open"] = "<li class='prev'>";
        $config["prev_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["next_tag_open"] = "<li class='next'>";
        $config["next_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["first_link"] = "<li>&lsaquo; First";
        $config["first_link"] = "</li>";
        $config["last_link"] = "<li>Last &rsaquo;";
        $config["last_link"] = "</li>";
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data["totalpage"]=$config['per_page'];
        $data['colorproduct'] = $this->mdashboard->GetAllcolorByPage($id,$config["per_page"], $page);
```

**View**

```
<? echo $this->pagination->create_links();?></div>
```

**Model**

```
$data = array();
    $Q = $this->db->select('*,(select pname from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as productname,(select image from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as image FROM tbl_productcolor where cid="'.$id.'" order by id asc ');
    $Q =  $this->db->get();

    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();  
    return $data;
```

Comment: where is $page defined?

Comment: @kumar_v actually I try this code from some ware reference

Comment: @kumar_v its done, thanks, need to add $page @ function productcolor($id=0,$page=0)

Answer (score 0):

U need to add limit to your query 
like this 
in ur model

```
function GetAllcolorByPage($id,$limit,$offset) {
    $data = array();
        $Q = $this->db->select('*,(select pname from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as productname,(select image from tbl_product where id=tbl_productcolor.pid)as image FROM tbl_productcolor where cid="'.$id.'" LIMIT'. $offset.' , '. $limit .' order by id asc ');
        $Q =  $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();  
    return $data; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the config as
$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;